# Ignoring specific folders in `.gitignore` not working as expected

Tags: python, git, github, gitlab, version-control

I'm encountering an issue with ignoring specific folders in my Git repository using the `.gitignore` file. Despite specifying folders to be ignored, the contents of these folders are still showing up in my Git status. Here's the setup:

**Directory Structure**:

```
project_directory/
├── .gitignore
└── notebooks/
    ├── __pycache__/
    │   └── example.pyc
    ├── .ipynb_checkpoints/
    │   └── notebook_checkpoint.ipynb
    ├── .Trash-0/
    │   └── deleted_file.txt
    ├── .pytest_cache/
    │   └── cache_contents.log
    ├── notebook1.ipynb
    ├── notebook2.ipynb
    ├── data/
    │   └── data.csv
    ├── images/
    │   └── image.jpg
    └── scripts/
        └── script.py
```

**`.gitignore` Contents**:

```
# Ignore specific folders inside notebooks directory
notebooks/__pycache__/
notebooks/.ipynb_checkpoints/
notebooks/.Trash-0/
notebooks/.pytest_cache/
```

**Steps Taken**:

1. I've executed the following commands to untrack the specified folders:

   ```bash
   git rm -r --cached notebooks/__pycache__/
   ```

   - Error: `fatal: pathspec 'notebooks/__pycache__/' did not match any files`

   ```bash
   git rm -r --cached notebooks/.ipynb_checkpoints/
   ```

   - Error: `fatal: pathspec 'notebooks/.ipynb_checkpoints/' did not match any files`

   ```bash
   git rm -r --cached notebooks/.Trash-0/
   ```

   - Error: `fatal: pathspec 'notebooks/.Trash-0/' did not match any files`

   ```bash
   git rm -r --cached notebooks/.pytest_cache/
   ```

   - Error: `fatal: pathspec 'notebooks/.pytest_cache/' did not match any files`
2. Following the untracking, I performed a commit with the message:

   ```bash
   git commit -m "Remove unwanted cache and temporary folders from tracking"
   ```

However, despite these steps, I'm still facing the issue where the contents of these folders are appearing in my Git status.

I've verified that I'm running these commands from the root directory of my repository.

Why is the `.gitignore` not working as expected in this scenario? Am I overlooking something in the process? How can I ensure that these folders and their contents are properly ignored and not included in my repository?

Comment: "*Despite specifying folders to be ignored, the contents of these folders are still showing up in my Git status.*" Please [edit] and show the text output of `git status`

Comment: everything is committed for `On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message

```
fatal: pathspec 'notebooks/.ipynb_checkpoints/' did not match any files
```

and similar most likely occur because those folders are not currently being tracked. Simply remove them with `rm -r`.

That said, I can't see your `.git` directory in `project_directory`. Is it there and you forgot to list it? As listed, your `.gitignore` should work, provided that you first `git init`'d your `project_directory` of course. Otherwise it's really not clear how to reproduce your error.

PROTIP: if you don't want the cache files to be created, add this to your bashrc or similar file in home:

```
# don't create pesky __pycache__ directories                                                            
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```

Comment: Thank you I figured out the problem but I can't get the bashrc to work. Along with the cache files I do not want the folders that contain `.ipynb_checkpoints` on all sub-directories

Comment: After you edit your bashrc file, you need to "source it" by doing `source ~/.bashrc`. Only then you will see an effect.